# Go JSON parsing error

Tags: json, go, yaml

I am writing my first program in Golang, or rather modifying a template, if you will. Want to parse values from a yaml file.

```
apiVersion: "backend.example.com/v1alpha1"
kind: "Example"
metadata:
  name: "solar-demo"
spec:
  size: 2
  group: backend.example.com
  names:
    kind: Example
    listKind: ExampleList
    plural: solar-demos
    singular: solar-demo
  scope: Namespaced
  version: v1alpha1
  pods:
    - name: api
      image: "shmukler/docker_solar-api"
      port: 3000
      command: '{"npm", "run", "start-api"}'
    - name: service
      image: "shmukler/docker_solar-svc"
      port: 3001
      command: '{"npm", "run", "start-solar-svc"}'
```

To parse-out variables, I do:

```
type Example struct {
    metav1.TypeMeta   `json:",inline"`
    metav1.ObjectMeta `json:"metadata"`
    Spec              ExampleSpec   `json:"spec"`
    Status            ExampleStatus `json:"status,omitempty"`
}
type ExampleSpec struct {
    Size int32 `json:"size"`
    //  Pods []ExamplePod `json:"pods"`
}
type ExampleStatus struct {
    Nodes []string `json:"nodes"`
}
type ExamplePod struct {
    Name    []string `json:"name"`
    Image   []string `json:"image"`
    Port    int32    `json:"port"`
    Command []string `json:"command"`
}
```

If I comment out the `Pods []ExamplePod` line, the code works albeit without parsing the Pods array. If I leave it in, there is an error, as soon as I pass the `yaml` document - `Observed a panic: &errors.errorString{s:"failed to decode json data with gvk...`

I want to stick `pods` into an array of structures of the type `ExamplePod`.

Today is my first day working with Go language. Sorry for a stupid question. My yaml, the relevant fragment in `JSON` representation.

```
spec":{  
   "group":"backend.example.com",
   "names":{  
      "kind”:”Example”,
      "listKind”:”ExampleList",
      "plural":"solar-demos",
      "singular":"solar-demo"
   },
   "pods":[  
      {  
         "command":"{\"npm\", \"run\", \"start-api\"}",
         "image":"shmukler/docker_solar-api",
         "name":"api",
         "port":3000
      },
      {  
         "command":"{\"npm\", \"run\", \"start-solar-svc\"}",
         "image":"shmukler/docker_solar-svc",
         "name":"service",
         "port":3001
      }
   ],
   "scope":"Namespaced",
   "size":2,
   "version":"v1alpha1"
}
```

I am able to get `example.Spec.Size` just fine. What I am missing is the `pods` array.

Comment: So you are trying to parse YAML with a JSON parser, right?

Comment: I use a library, if you will, converting `yaml` into `JSON`. This is not the problem. Is everything correct as far as my structures?

Comment: Which library are you using, it would be more helpful to paste in the converted json, or use a yaml parser directly such as https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml

Comment: Show the JSON, the full error returned from parsing the JSON and the code used to parse the JSON.

Comment: In ExampleSpec Command, Image, and Name should not be `[]string` but `string`. https://play.golang.org/p/J8yfhP5tJ3O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the suggestions from both offered answers changed the YAML to:

```
containers:
- name: api
  image: "shmukler/docker_solar-api"
  port: 3000
  command: ["npm", "run", "start-api"]
- name: service
  image: "shmukler/docker_solar-svc"
  port: 3001
  command: ["npm", "run", "start-solar-svc"]
```

Then, updated definitions to:

```
type Spec struct {
    Size       int32               `json:"size"`
    Containers []Container `json:"containers"`
}
type Status struct {
    Nodes []string `json:"nodes"`
}
type Container struct {
    Name    string   `json:"name"`
    Image   string   `json:"image"`
    Port    int32    `json:"port"`
    Command []string `json:"command"`
}
```

That finally worked fine.

Thank you for the answers, helped me to understand how Golang type definitions work.

Answer (score 3):

The JSON is invalid.  Replace `”` with `"` and add surrounding `{}`.

Change type of ExamplePod fields to string:

```
type ExamplePod struct {
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Image   string `json:"image"`
    Port    int32    `json:"port"`
    Command string `json:"command"`
}
```

[Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/pgHY8Lx_bZQ)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your yaml file is a definition for a Kubernetes object, which it looks like it is, your command is a slice of string so should, in the yaml  template be `command: ["some string"]`. This should parse correctly.

However if you are attempting to produce a Pod specification. Then this looks incorrect regardless. Command and Args should probably be different properties. [See K8 doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/).

Given what I have just said, I have expanded on and modified your example slightly and you can see that here https://play.golang.org/p/usS06f_H3NN. Even if it is not exactly what you need you should be able to modify it now accordingly.

Comment: You are correct about the Kubernetes. Neither `[".."]`, nor `""` helped. Still getting the same error: `panic: failed to decode json data with gvk(backend.example.com/v1alpha1, Kind=Example): v1alpha1.Example.Spec: v1alpha1.ExampleSpec.Pods: []v1alpha1.ExamplePod: v1alpha1.ExamplePod.Command: []string: decode slice: expect [ or n, but found ", error found in #10 byte of ...|command":"npm run st|..., bigger context ...|mos","singular":"solar-demo"},"pods":[{"command":"npm run start-api","image":"shmukler/docker_solar-|... [recovered]`

Comment: Can you edit your question and update the yaml and go code to exactly what you have now?